# How to sum objects' property within an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects, and I'm trying to sum all the `num`s in the array. The array looks like this:

```
var arr = [{"year": 2011, "num": 0}, {"year": 2012, "num": 2}, {"year": 2013, "num": 5}];
```

So the sum should be 7.

How do you calculate the total in Javascript?

I tried:

```
var sum = arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
});
```

But this returns:

```
"[object Object][object Object][object Object]"
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: Please show your efforts when asking for help. What have you tried? What issues did you have? Any errors?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Jonathan. I edited my question with more details.

Comment: That edit has rendered everyone's answers invalid. Perhaps adding a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would be useful.

Comment: Good point. I'll move the edits to a new question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you want to reduce an array of values to a single value. Use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
var a = [{"year": 2011, "num": 0}, {"year": 2012, "num": 2}, {"year": 2013, "num": 5}];
a.reduce(function(prev, curr) { return prev + curr.num }, 0);
7
```

`reduce` goes through each element of the array and accumulates a value using the function you pass it. The last argument is the initial value of `prev`.

This has "only" been in the [ECMAScript Language specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.21) since 2011, so if you need to support old browsers, you might like to try something like [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#reduce):

```
_.reduce(a, function(prev, curr) { return prev + curr.num }, 0);
```

This will fall back to the native implementation if such a thing exists.

Or if you like to roll your own, you can use a loop:

```
for (var i = 0, sum = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    sum += a[i].num;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var arr = [{"year": 2011, "num": 0}, {"year": 2012, "num": 2}, {"year": 2013, "num": 5}];
var sum = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    sum = sum + arr[i].num;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it...

```
function getSum(theArray){
    var sum = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i<theArray.length; i++){
        var sum += theArray[i].num
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = [{"year": 2011, "num": 0}, {"year": 2012, "num": 2}, {"year": 2013, "num": 5}];
var sum = 0;

arr.forEach(function(obj){
    sum += obj.num;
});

//now sum have 7
console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to turn it into an array of numbers, then [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to sum them:

```
var array = [{"year": 2011, "num": 0}, {"year": 2012, "num": 2}, {"year": 2013, "num": 5}];
var sum = array.map(function (a) {
    return a.num;
}).reduce(function (a, b) {
    return a + b;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to loop over the array and increment a variable:

```
var arr = [{"year": 2011, "num": 0}, {"year": 2012, "num": 2}, {"year": 2013, "num": 5}];
var sum = 0;
for(var obj in arr) {
    sum += arr[obj].num;
}
// sum now contains the value 7
```

[**Here's a working jsFiddle to demonstrate**](http://jsfiddle.net/TexasBrawler/c8J2A/).

Comment: What's with the down vote? This is a correct (and tested) answer.